# How to serialize Kotlin data-class with default values into JSON using kotlinx.serialization?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

There is an example of a class with a default value:

```
@Serializable
data class TestClass(
    val obligatory: String,
    val optional: Int = 0
)
```

It can be correctly deserialize from jsons like: `{ "obligatory":"text", "optional":1 }` and `{ "obligatory":"text" }`.
At the same time, the result of its serialization has to contain the attribute "optional".

As a result of serialization:

```
Json.encodeToString(TestClass("text"))
```

I expect `{ "obligatory":"text", "optional":0 }`, however now I have `{ "obligatory":"text" }`.

How should I change my code to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, Kotlinx Serialization [doesn't encode default values](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded-by-default). I guess it assumes you're using the same data model on the other side.

You can [force serializing default values](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#encoding-defaults) when you configure your serializer:

```
val json = Json { encodeDefaults = true }

json.encodeToString(TestClass("text"))
```

Since version 1.3.0, it is now also possible to change this behaviour only for specific properties using the `@EncodeDefault` annotation (independently of the format's config). So if you wanted this only for this specific property, you could write (and keep the default format config):

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class TestClass(
    val obligatory: String,
    @EncodeDefault
    val optional: Int = 0,
)
```

Conversely, if you have enabled the encoding of default values globally in your format configuration, you can override this behaviour to *not* encode the default for a specific property:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class TestClass(
    val obligatory: String,
    @EncodeDefault(EncodeDefault.Mode.NEVER)
    val optional: Int = 0,
)

val json = Json { encodeDefaults = true }
// then this will NOT encode the default, despite the format's config
json.encodeToString(TestClass("text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Joffrey mentioned you can configure the serializer.

Another option is to use the `@EncodeDefault` annotation as the documentation mentions:

```
@Serializable
data class TestClass(
    val obligatory: String,
    @EncodeDefault val optional: Int = 0
)
```